How to access current velocity of a sprite in Phaser JS
Is there a way to get the current velocity of a sprite in Phaser or another obvious way of finding when the player is still?

Did you try googling this first?  I found 2 useful results just by typing in your question

Try something like the example below.  More info about Phasers velocity here
// X velocity 
sprite.body.velocity.x
// Y velocity 
sprite.body.velocity.y

